# Help me with linearly dependent and independent vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V be a real vector space, {v1,...,vn} be subsets of vectors and w∈V. Prove that if {v1,...,vn} is linearly independent and {v1+w,v2+w,...,vn-1+w,vn+w} is linearly dependent, the w∈span[v1,...,vn]

Is it saying that {v1,...,vn} is set of 0 vectors when it is a linearly independent? Such that {t1v1+t2v2+...+tnvn} are all zero since t1=t2=tn=0

Then {v1+w,v2+w,...,vn-1+w,vn+w} be {o+w,0+w...0+w}?
and w∈span[v1,...,vn] be w={t1v1+t2v2+...+tnvn}..??
then shouldnt this also be linealy independent?

im confused please help
Thank you

Comment: Take a linear combination of the elements of the dependent set that equal 0. Then move all terms with w to other side. Now we have a linear combination of the independent set equalling some multiple of w. Dividing out that multiple on both sides, you have w as a linear combination of v1,...vn

Answer (score 0):

No that is not what it is saying. To say that a set $\{v_1, v_2, ..., v_n\}$ of vectors is linearly independent means that none of them can be written as a linear combination of the others. That is, for every $k$, it is always true that $$v_k \ne a_1v_1 + ... + a_{k-1}v_{k-1} + a_kv_k + ... +a_nv_n$$ for any scalars $a_i$. If you could express one of the vectors in terms of the others this way, then that particular vector doesn't add anything new. It becomes redundant. Any vector that you could express as a linear combination of the entire set could also be expressed as a linear combination of the non-redundant vectors alone.

Now, this looks different than the definition you've been given, but it is actually equivalent. That definition is: the vectors are linearly independent if whenever
$$a_1v_1 + ... +a_nv_n = 0$$
it must be true that the scalars $a_i = 0$ for every $i$. (Note that this says the *scalar* values $a_i$ are $0$, **not** the vectors!)

To see that these are the same, it is easiest to show that one of the conditions can be false if and only the other is false.

If the first version is false, then there is a $k$ and values $a_i$ such that 
$$v_k \ne a_1v_1 + ... + a_{k-1}v_{k-1} + a_kv_k + ... +a_nv_n$$
But then if we subtract $v_k$ from both sides and let $a_k = -1$, this gives
$$a_1v_1 + ... +a_nv_n = 0$$
and since $a_k$ is not $0$, the second version is false as well.

Conversely, if we know that $$b_1v_1 + ... +b_nv_n = 0$$ for some $b_i$ and at least one of the $b_i$ is not $0$, then let $k$ be such that $b_k \ne 0$. Then we can rearrange the sum to be
$$ v_k = \frac{b_1}{-b_k}v_1 + ... +\frac{b_{k-1}}{-b_k}v_{k-1} + \frac{b_{k+1}}{-b_k}v_{k+1} + ...+ \frac{b_{n}}{-b_k}v_{n}$$
Therefore the first condition is false, too.

I hope that helps clear up your confusion over what linearly independent means. Yunus Syed has told you how you really solve this problem.